# NodeWebkit Prevent window from closing on startup

Tags: node-webkit

I have pinpointed the error in my app.js that apparently crashes the NW window.
What happens is on the startup when that line is executed, window simply closes without any information. 
How can I force it to stay open, and maybe look in the console window for more details.

Answer (score 0):

without looking at your code it is impossible to know why, but I'll try to take an educated guess. You probably have an exception with crashes your app.

From past experience the most common exception is caused due to incorrect call to window:

> **window**: defined as a property of 'global', points to the DOM window
>   global object. Note that it would be updated upon page navigation.
>   This symbol is not available at the time the script is loaded, because
>   the script is executed before the DOM window load ([source](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main))

So if you use 'node-main' and in there you use 'window' your app will crash on startup. The solution is to run any code that requires the `window` object under your `main` script as configured in the `package.json` file.

Comment: Could you provide more details? I am afraid I do not understand it correctly :(. On this thread I provided more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411426/debugging-nodewebkit-with-webstorm