# Debugging Nodewebkit with Webstorm

Tags: javascript, express, node-webkit

I am trying to open a NW in a Webstorm so I can start debugging. When I have erro r in the App, NW windows just closes without any hint why that happened.

I have found this [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-node-webkit.html) on the Webstorm website. In my root folder I have app.js that contains usual express app start up and module inclusion. Also I have package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"window": {
"toolbar": true,
"width": 800,
"height": 500
},
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "jquery": "^2.1.4",
 "nw": "^0.12.2",
 "pretty-bytes": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

And I have the following index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My App</title>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = 'http://localhost:3000';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two issues with this:

1. When I run NW alone (just double click the nw.exe), app will launch, but not always. in 10 times, it will just close 3 times. The rest will open normally.
2. I have followed instruction on the Webstorm site how to debug it, and with strange results. When I try to open it inside webstorm, NE window shows, and imidiately closes with this error: Process finished with exit code 0
   But I can open the applicaiton in the webstorm in normal mode (not debugg).

What is going on in here?
My Webstorm debug screen:
[image]

Comment: If you can get your hands on OSX, debugging is very easier.  You can run NW from iTerm and you can see all the errors in iTerm.  You can also console.log for debugging and those messages will be output to iTerm as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with windows environment :(

Comment: I've used NW in OSX, Windows and Linux and have found OSX to be most useful.  I'm sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't post any of your code, but you probably get an exception that makes the app crash immediately.

From past experience the most common exception is caused due to incorrect call to window:

> **window**: defined as a property of 'global', points to the DOM window
>   global object. Note that it would be updated upon page navigation.
>   This symbol is not available at the time the script is loaded, because
>   the script is executed before the DOM window load ([source](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main))

So if you use 'node-main' and in there you use 'window' your app will crash on startup. Look for any call to window in app.js and try to comment it. if it works - you need to put the code in functions and call them from index.html.

if this is not the case, you need to debug your code to find why it breaks. try omitting code blocks to find the bug. you can post your code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the debug configuration in Webstorm? It is separate from the normal mode.

If you need to see console messages in Windows, use Git Bash

Comment: I have added an image on my question showing the Webstorm debug setup. As for the debug mode using GitBash... you mean that I startup app.js in git bash?

Comment: Ah I see. The part that reads "NW.js app" needs to be pointing to an executable application. Probably app.js. And yes you can start up your application in Git bash, as an alternative to Webstorm.

Comment: The NW.js app is accepting only folder as a parameter, not a single file. I know that I can run node app.js in gitbash (works in win CMD as well)... but what good it can do me while debbugging NW app?

Comment: Ok very good. Have you compared the normal to debug config? I would imagine they should be similar, if not already.

Comment: Tehy are the same. App runs in normal mode, while in debug give me this error: 

nw.exe --remote-debugging-port=35497 --url=data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PHRpdGxlPkxvYWRpbmcgZmlsZTovLy9EOiU1Q0glNUN2My9pbmRleC5odG1sPC90aXRsZT4= D:\H\v3

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a reason why my NW window was closing sometimes. This is my setup:

package.json:

```
 "main": "index.html",
 "node-main": "appnw.js",
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout (function () {
    window.location = 'http://localhost:9000';
},1000)
```

Problem was in fact that sometimes Express.js server did not start while NW was trying to "get" it. I simply used setTimout to slow it down:

```
  setTimeout ( function () {
      app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {          
   });
  }, 2000);
```